# Dynamically build SQL and statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I write the following SQL query:

```
'Select *
from Address
where cityname like %1
and zipcode = %2'
```

when zipcode is optional?

Zipcode is optained from a urlquery. So it might be empty or likely a valid zip code.

If it is empty (''), the query should return all rows, if it is not empty, it should work as an additional 'and' parameter to the query.

Comment: How about a simple "if"-statement? If it is empty ->  Select * from Address where cityname like %1.    If not empty -> Select * from Address where cityname like %1 and zipcode = %2

Comment: @Danieboy of course I did come up with this posibility as well. I am ok at writing SQL queries but not so good when it comes to security. My concern would be injections etc. If I dynamically add more parameters, I also have to track that fact when passing the parameters to prepare the sql statement in the programming language before sending it to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM address
WHERE cityname LIKE %1
  AND zipcode = COALESCE(NULLIF(%2, ''), zipcode);
```

If `%2` is empty, `NULLIF` will return `NULL`, `COALESCE` will return `zipcode` and the condition will evaluate to `TRUE`.